# Mobile app testing with jmeter, internet connecrion does not work after conguiring proxy settings

Tags: testing, jmeter, wifi, connectivity, recorder

I am doing a mobile test recording with jmeter, after i configure my mobile proxy settings to system ip and port to math jmeter. Internet stops working? P.S. i already installed the ApacheJmeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of "mobile" operating systems and we are not telepathic enough to figure out which one you're talking about in order to provide troubleshooting instructions. I assume you use Android as it is about 75% of market.

1. Make sure to start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) prior to amending mobile device proxy settings
2. Make sure JMeter and mobile device are on the same subnet (connected to the same WiFi network)
3. Make sure that port `8888` is open in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
4. On certain Android versions you cannot set system proxy for HTTPS traffic, you will need to install a separate application like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) for this
5. If nothing helps you can always consider an alternative way of recording mobile traffic, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and you will get confidence that your device is connected to the Internet. See [Testing Mobile sites and Apps](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420335-Testing-Mobile-sites-and-Apps) article for more details.

Comment: sir, i have taken into considerarion all the steps you mentioned, and i am using android 7 device for testing ,

Answer (score 0):

I am very late here, but still this may help others who are still facing this issue.
In beginning i faced the same issue. Then, I tried by disabling the firewall. It worked fine.
Also disabling firewall may create a way for malicious contents to enter. Try only for trusted sources.